# Update table with data from other table

Tags: mysql

I want to update a table with values from another table, but these tables have no direct link so I have to go through another table first.

```
 UPDATE properties 
 SET  
 properties.method = p_payment.method,
 properties.bank = p_payment.bank, 
 properties.bank_account_nr = p_payment.bank_account_nr, 
 properties.payment_note = p_payment.notes,
 properties.insurance_policy = p_payment.insurance_policy 
 FROM properties, leads, p_payment 
 WHERE properties.owner = leads.id_lead
 AND leads.payment_id = p_payment.payment_id;
```

I get the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM properties, leads, p_payment WHERE properties.owner =
>   leads.id_lead AND l' at line 8

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing `UPDATE` syntax of `SQL Server`.

Here's `MySQL` version of `UPDATE`,

```
UPDATE  properties 
        INNER JOIN leads 
            ON properties.owner = leads.id_lead 
        INNER JOIN p_payment  
            ON leads.payment_id = p_payment.payment_id
SET     properties.method = p_payment.method,
        properties.bank = p_payment.bank, 
        properties.bank_account_nr = p_payment.bank_account_nr, 
        properties.payment_note = p_payment.notes,
        properties.insurance_policy = p_payment.insurance_policy
```